# SUM timespan column if date column matches today?

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula, sumifs

I have a spreadsheet I use to log my work.  Each row has a `Time Started` and `Time Ended` column then a `Time Spent` column that is automatically calculated as the difference between the previous two.  What I'm trying to do now is have a field called `Hours Today` that will do a `SUM` of `Time Spent` for those rows with a `Time Ended` that matches today's date.

Here is sample data:

```
Time Started        Time Ended          Time Spent
-------------------|-------------------|----------
12/7/15 8:00 AM     12/7/15 8:28 AM     0:28
12/7/15 8:28 AM     12/7/15 8:44 AM     0:15
12/7/15 8:44 AM     12/7/15 9:10 AM     0:26
12/7/15 9:10 AM     12/7/15 10:00 AM    0:50
12/7/15 10:00 AM    12/7/15 10:32 AM    0:31
12/7/15 10:32 AM    12/7/15 10:53 AM    0:21
12/7/15 10:54 AM    12/7/15 12:00 PM    1:06
12/7/15 12:00 PM    12/7/15 12:39 PM    0:38
12/7/15 12:39 PM    12/7/15 12:52 PM    0:13
12/7/15 12:52 PM    12/7/15 1:33 PM     0:40
12/7/15 1:33 PM     12/7/15 1:50 PM     0:17
12/7/15 1:50 PM     12/7/15 2:50 PM     1:00
12/7/15 2:51 PM     12/7/15 2:55 PM     0:04
12/7/15 2:56 PM     12/7/15 3:16 PM     0:20
12/7/15 3:16 PM     12/7/15 3:20 PM     0:03
12/7/15 3:20 PM     12/7/15 3:44 PM     0:24
12/7/15 3:44 PM     12/7/15 5:08 PM     1:23
12/8/15 8:05 AM     12/8/15 8:24 AM     0:18
12/8/15 8:24 AM     12/8/15 9:00 AM     0:35
12/8/15 9:00 AM     12/8/15 9:58 AM     0:58
12/8/15 9:58 AM     12/8/15 10:17 AM    0:18
12/8/15 10:17 AM    12/8/15 11:00 AM    0:42
12/8/15 11:00 AM    12/8/15 11:56 AM    0:56
12/8/15 11:56 AM    12/8/15 12:13 PM    0:17
12/8/15 12:13 PM    12/8/15 2:20 PM     2:07
12/8/15 2:20 PM     12/8/15 2:40 PM     0:20
12/8/15 2:40 PM     12/8/15 3:00 PM     0:19
12/8/15 3:00 PM     12/8/15 3:41 PM     0:41
```

Here is the formula I tried most recently but it says it's not valid.

```
SUMIF(DAY(tblTrack[Time Ended]),DAY(TODAY()),tblTrack[Time Spent])
```

**How can I sum the difference of two timestamps if one of the timestamps matches today?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
=SUMIFS(tblTrack[Time Spent],tblTrack[Time Ended],">="&TODAY(),tblTrack[Time Ended],"<="&TODAY()+1)
```

The issue is `Today()` gives the value of `12/8/2018 0:00`  So none of your end time will match.  So we use `SUMIFS()` to set the range between 12:00am this morning and 12:00am tomorrow.

Comment: @pnuts Yes that is what I got.  Had you already posted this formula in the comments?

Comment: This made me realize my initial formula had the parameters flipped.  This is more elegant anyway, thanks!